# Repeating 2 methods to make into 1 method

Tags: c#

I have this repeating code , and I'm unsure of how I can make it in only 1 method.

```
public int isWonVertical()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        {
            resetCounter();
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            {
                if (raster[j, i] == 1) counterPlayer1++;
                else counterPlayer1 = 0;

                if (raster[j, i] == 2) counterPlayer2++;
                else counterPlayer2 = 0;

                if (counterPlayer1 == tokenStreak) return 1;
                if (counterPlayer2 == tokenStreak) return 2;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }//isWonVertical


public int isWonHorizontal()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            resetCounter();
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                if (raster[i, j] == 1) counterPlayer1++;
                else counterPlayer1 = 0;

                if (raster[i, j] == 2) counterPlayer2++;
                else counterPlayer2 = 0;

                if (counterPlayer1 == tokenStreak) return 1;
                if (counterPlayer2 == tokenStreak) return 2;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }//isWonHorizontal
```

The **returns** and **resetCounter()** I can all put in 1 method. But how do I make sure the for loops are different for vertical/horizontal. I assume it's with giving parameters with, and then checking wether I gave 'vertical' or 'horizontal' as a paramter. But i'm unsure how to make this actually work.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing this for performance? Are the methods ever called separately? Does `counterPlayerx` need to be class-level (or wherever you have it)?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to. You're asking 2 different questions from 2 different methods, which seems correct. If anything, you can refactor some of the duplicate code out of each method into a third one.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Yes for performance, but more for "do not write the same code twice". counterPlayerX is only used in the class where I'm using the methods.

Comment: @aw04 That's exactly what I want, I want to refactor the duplicate code into a third one.

Comment: Got it. @Dom (+1) has a good answer below.

Answer (score 5):

```
public int isWon(DirectionEnum enum)
    {
        int counter1 = enum == DirectionEnum.IsVertical ? columns : rows;
        int counter2 = enum == DirectionEnum.IsHorizontal ? columns: rows; 
        for (int i = 0; i < counter1 ; i++)
        {
            resetCounter();
            for (int j = 0; j < counter2; j++)
            {
                if (raster[i, j] == 1) counterPlayer1++;
                else counterPlayer1 = 0;

                if (raster[i, j] == 2) counterPlayer2++;
                else counterPlayer2 = 0;

                if (counterPlayer1 == tokenStreak) return 1;
                if (counterPlayer2 == tokenStreak) return 2;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This would probably be better as `isWon(DirectionEnum direction)`; the naming is otherwise confusing. What happens if you could win diagonally (or something else that a `bool` can't handle).

Comment: The **raster** is also different , so I assume just also make 2 variables for the **raster** ?

Comment: @JSadones Is raster the same type in both cases? Just pass it in as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How about his, two parameters, one for the inner array, one for the outer. Then your client (calling code) needs to decide what to use as inner or outer, either rows or columns

```
public int isWon(outerArray, innerArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < outerArray; i++)
    {
        resetCounter();
        for (int j = 0; j < innerArray; j++)
        {
            if (raster[i, j] == 1) counterPlayer1++;
            else counterPlayer1 = 0;

            if (raster[i, j] == 2) counterPlayer2++;
            else counterPlayer2 = 0;

            if (counterPlayer1 == tokenStreak) return 1;
            if (counterPlayer2 == tokenStreak) return 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On the downside, this doesn't provide for a clear API, so it can be improved.